# <?php echo $_SESSION doesnt display on site

Tags: php, mysql, session

I downloaded a php login source and now it works and it even logs in. when it logs in it shows your name with

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
```

but i also want to display there balance by putting

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['balance']; ?>
```

But it doesnt display the balance?

https://gyazo.com/7cd0a7888ac976590391888925d0c18f

I added the balance table to the existing tables.

I really dont know what to do! :(

Comment: You know you have to add it to the session before you can echo it?

Comment: have you started the session? with  session_start();

Comment: Did you ever do `$_SESSION['balance'] = "initial value";` before trying to output the content? The variable will not be filled up automatically by magic.

Comment: sorry i just started programming ,  where do i put session_start()?

Comment: The contents of `$_SESSION` aren't automatically mapped to the contents of a database table, if that is what you think should be happening. It is not - instead you should read the contents from the database table and insert it into the variable yourself if you want to use it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Please Insert;

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

In every page where you want to access `$_SESSION` global array.

in your case;

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
$_SESSION['balance'] = 1000;
echo $_SESSION['balance']; // will output 1000.
```

suppose this page was **set-session-value.php** and you want to get this `$_SESSION['balance']` value in **get-session-value.php** do as follow in **get-session-value.php** file;

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
echo $_SESSION['balance'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your login.php add this line after setting session for username

```
$_SESSION["balance"]=$balance;
```

And in your home, it is always advised to check if session exists and then print it. So,

```
if(isset($_SESSION["balance"])){echo $_SESSION["balance"]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`start session` before use

```
<?php
session_start();//start session

$_SESSION['username']='abc';//Set value session
$_SESSION['balance']=10;

echo $_SESSION['username']; //Use value of session
echo $_SESSION['balance'];
?>
```

> please use this process for session use

Comment: I think the user has already used `session_start()` as he mentions print balance similar to username, but if he hasn't then its very good you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

When you logged into your application.After that you should want to add following code into top of the page.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $userNameValue;//set user name
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

And then you should want to fetch data related to who logged user from your `user table` by using query.

```
Example

   $query = "SELECT * YOURTABLENAME WHERE username='$_SESSION['username']'";
   mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
   $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Then you can assign to $_SESSION['balance'] for value like this;

```
$_SESSION['balance'] = $data['balance'];

echo  $_SESSION['balance'];
```